# Rails 4, raw query using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there currently a way to do a raw SQL select query using ActiveRecord in Rails 4.0.0.beta1? I see ActiveRecord::Base.execute no longer exists. What's the correct way of going about this?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Here try this, select example.. :

```
query = "select ...."
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

Comment: Apparently this is deprecated when calling this from a controller. `DEPRECATION WARNING: #connection is deprecated in favour of accessing it via the class.`

Comment: this is because you should let model interact with the database instead of accessing the database directly in the controller

Comment: @ant should I open transaction or open connection will be enough for custom sql query execution ? [pastie example](http://pastie.org/10111824)

Comment: @gaussblurinc I believe you should be aware whether you are already in a transaction and if so then do note what database you are using (capable of nested transactions?). Unless you need some more complicated/separated result, I'd suggest you go with the plain way given in the example above. Or go with transaction if you may wish to experiment and do a rollback when you are finished.

Answer (score 30):

Just to add my ten pence, a raw query using Model.connection.execute won't return an ActiveRecord model - it'll return a raw data set.

The following will return ActiveRecord models:

```
MyModel.find_by_sql(query)
```

edit: assuming of course that you're running a select.

Answer (score 10):

In Rails 4 (perhaps previous versions as well), if you're going with a custom query for speed, you can add a `:skip_logging` argument to avoid writing to the log:

```
query = "SELECT ..."
results = MyModel.connection.execute(query, :skip_logging)
```

(Note: If I'm reading the sources correctly, this might not hold true in PostgreSQL.)

Comment: how do I prevent SQL injections?

Comment: that would make an excellent question all by itself (unless it's already been answered) -- don't you agree?